# Can't make @Formula attributes work with CriteriaBuilder

Tags: java, jpa, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I have an entity like the following were I use `@Formula` to populate `clientId` from other tables.

```
@Entity
public class Failure {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    public int id;
    public String name;
    @ManyToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REFRESH} )
    public PVPlant pvPlant;

    @Formula("(SELECT cl.id from failure f " +
            "INNER JOIN pvplant p ON f.pv_plant_id = p.id " +
            "INNER JOIN company co ON p.company_id = co.id "+
            "INNER JOIN client cl ON co.client_id = cl.id "+
            "WHERE f.id = id) ")
    public Integer clientId;
}
```

while `CrudRepository<Failure,Integer>` JPA method `getByClientId` works fine I am trying to make something more dynamic for filtering using a `Map` of keys and values with `Specification` and `CriteriaBuilder`.

```
public MySpecifications {

    public static Specification<Failure> equalToEachColumn(HashMap<String,Object> map) {

        return new Specification<Failure>() {
            @Override
            public Predicate toPredicate(Root<Failure> root, CriteriaQuery<?> cq, CriteriaBuilder builder) {

                return builder.and(root.getModel().getAttributes().stream().map(a ->
                        {
                            if (map.containsKey(a.getName())) {
                                    Object val = map.get(a.getName());
                                    return builder.equal(root.<Integer>get(a.getName()), Integer.parseInt(val.toString()));
                            }
                            return builder.disjunction();
                        }
                    ).toArray(Predicate[]::new)
                );
            }
        };
    }

 }
```

When I am passing `id` in the `HashMap` it works fine but when I have `clientId` it doesn't send anything back. It is interesting that `getAttributes()` actually returns `clientId` but it seems that `builder.equal(root.<Integer>get(a.getName()), Integer.parseInt(val.toString()))` is false and not true

This is how I am using the Specification:

```
failureRepository.findAll(Specifications.where(MySpecifications.equalToEachColumn(map)));
```

Am I missing something?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The actual problem was that I was using

`builder.disjunction()`

in the `and()` which creates 0=1 false predicates.

When I replaced it with

`builder.conjunction()` (which creates 1=1 true predicates)

in my code it worked fine. So `@Formula` properties behave as native ones to the table and it seems there is no need for `SecondaryTable` and a new `View`. Apparently in my earlier tests I used an entity that had just an id in its class and when I added `clientId` it misled me to believe that `@Formula` properties don't work, while it was the disjunction from the id that broke clientId

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't expect this to work however you could make it work by using a database view as an alternative to `@Formula` and mapping the entity across the table and view using `@SecondaryTable`.

```
//failures_client_vw is a 2 column db view: failure_id, client_id
@Table(name = "failures")
@SecondaryTable(name = "failures_client_vw",  
       pkJoinColumns = @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "failure_id"))
@Entity
public class Failure {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    public int id;

    public String name;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REFRESH} )
    public PVPlant pvPlant;

    @Column(name = "client_id", table = "failures_client_vw")
    public Integer clientId;
}
```

You can then query clientId as you would any other property.

https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Tables#Multiple_tables

Comment: thanks! interesting! i didnt know I could use a complementary view for just one property that its use would be transparent to my repositories and queries! I will try it soon :)